# Taxonomy and Date in same query?

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, date

Is is possible to combine a tax_query with a date_query in the most recent Wordpress?

Here's my attempt to do so:

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'job',
'tax_query' => array(  
       array(  
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
        'terms' => 'dallas',
        'field' => 'slug',
       )  
 ),
 'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'year' => '2014',
        'month' => '12',
    ),
  )
);
$jobs = new WP_Query($args);
```

However, it is ignoring the date query and only the taxonomy query works. When I remove the taxonomy query portion, the date query suddenly works.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code I ended up using, since there doesn't seem to be a way of introducing "OR" as a relation in the query. This just checks which query is occuring from the query string, then applies the correct args to the WP_Query. Hope all this makes sense!

```
<?php
$locationq = $_REQUEST["location"]; 
$monthq = $_REQUEST['month'];
$yearq = $_REQUEST['year'];
$searchq = $_REQUEST['keyword'];

//list terms in a given taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'careerlocation';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
echo '<div class="careerbox locationpicker">';
echo '<select class="locationlinks">';
echo '<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a region</option>';
echo '<option value="">View All</a></li>';
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    echo '<option value="?location='.$tax_term->slug.'">' . $tax_term->name . '</option>'."\n";
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</div>';

//list month and year of listed positions
echo '<div class="careerbox datepicker">';
echo '  <select class="datelinks">';
echo '    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Date Posted</option>';
$current_date = "";
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
$nextpost = 0;
$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
$myposts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'career',
  'posts_per_page' => $published_posts
)); 
foreach($myposts as $post) :
    $nextpost++;
    setup_postdata($post);
    $date = get_the_date("F Y");   
    if($current_date!=$date): 
        //echo '<option value="">'. $date .'</option>';
        $dt = strtotime($date);
        $month=date('m',$dt);
        $year=date('Y',$dt);
        echo '<option value="?month='.$month.'&year='.$year.'">'. $date .'</option>';
        $current_date = $date;
    endif;
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
echo '  </select>';
echo '</div>';
?>
           </div>
<?php
//now run query filter on either date or location
if($locationq) {
$qu = 'tax_query';
$typequery = array(  
    array(  
        'taxonomy' => 'careerlocation',
        'terms' => $locationq,
        'field' => 'slug',
        'operator' => 'IN',
        'include_children' => false
    )
);
} else if($monthq || $yearq) {
$qu = 'date_query';
$typequery = array(
    array(
        'year' => intval($yearq),
        'month' => intval($monthq),
        'compare' => '='
    )
);
} else if($searchq) {
$qu = 's';
$typequery = $searchq;
}
$jobargs = array(
'post_type' => 'career',
$qu => $typequery
);
$careersq = new WP_Query($jobargs);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the [date parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters); you'll need to enter an integer (number), not a string (text). Simply get rid of the single quotes to make it work:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'job',
  'tax_query' => array(  
    array(  
      'taxonomy' => 'location',
      'terms' => 'dallas',
      'field' => 'slug'
    )  
  ),
  'date_query' => array(
    array(
      'year' => 2014,
      'month' => 12
    ),
  )
);

$jobs = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Actually, those are coming through as variables, so in my working code there are no quotes. It looks like this: 'year' => $year,

Comment: I've just tested with real integers, no quotes, and it's still coming up empty.

Comment: @f8xmulder Are you sure about the output of `$year`? Maybe this will help: `(int)$year`

Comment: Just tried 'year' => intval(2014) and 'year' => 2014

Still nothing...

Comment: @f8xmulder Well, `'year' => 2014, 'month' => 12` is in the future; are you sure that there are posts? ;)

Comment: Ha, that would be correct. I misposted. The month is set to 5 (and there are 4 posts that should appear for May).

Comment: @f8xmulder Are you getting any results only for the year? Try to use `var_dump()` to check if there are any errors with the `date_query`; the date parameters are available since Version 3.7

Comment: So I've done some additional testing. It appears that my taxonomy term was blank, and no results were appearing. If I manually add a term that exists, it works with the date query. Shouldn't there be a way to do a relation of OR between the tax_query and the date_query to enable either one to work, even if one is blank?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14933/discussion-between-f8xmulder-and-sven).

Answer (score 0):

A bit more digging. I was able to do a conditional based on the querystring, and run a separate query.

Here's my final solution:

```
if($locationq) {
$qu = 'tax_query';
$typequery = array(  
    array(  
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
        'terms' => $locationq,
        'field' => 'slug',
        'operator' => 'IN',
        'include_children' => false
    )
);
} else if($monthq || $yearq) {
$qu = 'date_query';
$typequery = array(
    array(
        'year' => intval($yearq),
        'month' => intval($monthq),
        'compare' => '='
    )
);
} 
$jobargs = array(
'post_type' => 'career',
$qu => $typequery
);
```